# Reordering input fields during localization

Tags: html, angularjs, localization, globalization

I have inherited a product coded using AngularJS and I have a question regarding localization.

There's an HTML section that specifies two input fields of type input-number, one for a number of days and another for a number of months. As part of localizing the product we need to change the order in which the input fields appear, but only for certain languages.

Something like:

- English -> Number of days [#Days], number of months [#Months]
- Japanese -> Number of months [#Months], number of days [#Days]

What would be a good way of doing this? This is rather straightforward if you want to rearrange text but I haven't been able to find how to rearrange fields. We could have two different HTML sections, one for each of the orderings, but I'm hoping there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Could do it with css flexbox which allows you to set order. Different class on container would swap order of child elements

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Ended up defining the different fields as separate ng-template items. Then loaded the right input field using ng-include, after parsing the localized string and identifying the input field order.